# How to choose particular gem in Gemfile based on current RVM?

Tags: jruby, rvm

How can I conditionally choose which gem to use based on the Ruby VM currently in use?

Ideally I would like something like:

```
if [using jruby]
    gem 'jruby-openssl'
```

This would only require the jruby-openssl if the RVM being used is JRuby.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attempting to answer my own question here.

We can do this using the following Gemfile directive:

```
if defined?(JRUBY_VERSION)
  gem 'jdbc-sqlite3'
else
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

Answer (score 12):

Use the following in your Gemfile, as documented here:  https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter

```
platforms :ruby do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

platforms :jruby do
  gem 'jruby-openssl'
  gem 'activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter'
end
```